# DateListPlot Didn't Display the Data

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I'm trying to plot the data with **DateListPlot** function, but having some issues with the output.

Here is what I'm doing.  I'm downloading and parsing *RAW JSON* like this and extracting *values* section from it:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "matrix",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "metric_name"
        },
        "values": [
          [
            1556901190.699,
            "91158"
          ],
          [
            1556901220.699,
            "91160"
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The raw dataset (after JSON processing) looks like below (with the first element for each of three lists below is a *UnixTimeStamp*):

```
Inn[1]:=  input = {{1.557343390585`*^9, "120587"}, {1.557343420585`*^9, 
   "120589"}, {1.557343450585`*^9, "120591"}}

Out[1]:=  {{1.55734*10^9, "120587"}, {1.55734*10^9, "120589"}, {1.55734*10^9, "120591"}}
```

Then, dates are being converted to time objects and the entire object converted to the list of lists:

```
In[115]:=  dates = Partition[Map[FromUnixTime, input[[All, 1]]], 1]
```

[image: Out[115]]

And datapoints converted to the list of list as well (for merging in the next phase):

```
In[116]:=  values = Partition[input[[All, 2]], 1]
Out[116]:=  {{"120587"}, {"120589"}, {"120591"}}
```

As the final step, I'm trying to plot the data using DateListPlot:

```
In[120]:=  DateListPlot[Join[dates, values, 2], PlotRange -> All]
```

But getting the following output:

[image: DateListPlot]

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DateListPlot needs to plot {date, number} pairs, while you have {date, string} pairs.

Comment: Thank you, Carl!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Carl, I've made the following adjustment:

Instead of

```
In[116]:=  values = Partition[input[[All, 2]], 1]
```

I used the following code (using *FromDigits* function to convert *strings* to *numbers*)

```
In[116]:=  values = Partition[Map[FromDigits, input[[All, 2]]], 1]
```